# Upgrade to specific build of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a software development platform (Progress OpenEdge) that is not yet supported on Windows 10 1803. It is however supported on Windows 10 1709. I have a PC on 1607 that I need to update to 1709, but it seems it will go straight to 1803. If I install 1803 then the customer would no longer be supported by Progress.

How can I force it to update to 1709 instead?

Comment: Use the option to “delay feature updates” for at least 180 days. That will keep you a major version behind until the software vendors catch up. As long as you haven’t started downloading the 1803 update, Windows will only download 1709. You can also switch to the semi-annual channel for updates, which will also delay major updates for a few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the upgrade with an windows 10 1709 iso, but such way might force you to download it from msdn if you don’t find it online

A example howto to a manual upgrade with an iso for the creator update; https://windowsreport.com/install-windows-10-creators-update-iso-file/amp/

Comment: This method no longer works as the tool always downloads the last build